# Output a string to mysql terminal from external file

Tags: mysql, terminal

Simple question, but is there a way of outputting a line to the mysql terminal?

Let's say I have the following external sql file:

```
print "Fruit!";
SELECT * FROM fruit;
print "...and veggies!";
SELECT * FROM vegetables;
```

And in the mysql terminal I write:

```
source foods.sql
```

I would like to get the following:

```
Fruit
id    name
0     apple
1     orange

and veggies!
id    name
0     apple
1     orange
```

Is this possible and how would it be done?  Can't for the life of me find an answer.

Comment: Don't you think it would be more appropriate to use a batch file or a shell script to do that?

Comment: I suppose it would.  Just one more file to think about, but that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can...

(1) Throw a bunch of SQL into a file then pipe that content to MySQL. `$ cat commands.sql | mysql -u user --password=pass database`

(2) You can, alternatively, write your own bash script do some amount of this. Something like

```
MYSQL="mysql -u user --password=pass database"

echo "Fruits"
echo "SELECT * FROM fruits" | $MYSQL
echo "and veggies..."
echo "SELECT * FROM veggies" | $MYSQL
```

Comment: Great idea!  Never really thought about stepping outside of the sql.